# How to test google search box (software testing)

Tags: testing, architecture

Today I got this from an interviewer. I am not sure if anyone cell tell me what should be the right way. Thanks

Below is the question

**Consider www.google.com's search box and the Google Search button.**

1. Q: How would you test this functionality?
2. How would you design test automation for 1) above?

Answer (score 0):

When you're testing something, you want to find the points where the function, webpage, application, etc. *break*. It's unlikely that the interviewer is asking you to test search box portion of the Google homepage itself, as that is fairly simple (it's little more than a text input and a couple submit inputs inside a form), but rather find potential edge cases in the code which takes that input and produces the search results.

So, consider edge cases for a text input and a submit button in a form using a GET action:

- What happens if you submit the form with no input?
- What happens if you submit the form with too much input? (Both server and browser may impose limits on the URL generated by the GET, and those limits may be different.)
- What happens if you include characters which have special meaning in a GET query string such as `&` and `=`?
- What happens if you circumvent the page entirely, creating a different `<form>` which submits to the same page as Google's search box? What if you do this with some input values missing?